# YouTube Objective C GData API with ARC for iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

I am using YouTube Objective C GData API in my iOS application.

My app is in ARC, but GData API is in non ARC mode. I have searched to find the ARC objective c api for it, but no luck.

Also tried converting the api to arc by doing the following,
1. Manual conversion.
2. Converting the library into static library.
3. Giving the -fno-objc-arc flag in compiled sources of the files.

But nothing seems to work.

I just need to know where could i get the api with ARC. or any way to get it converted it to ARC.

Thanks,
Easwar

Answer (score 0):

Select Target -> Build Phases. Open the Compile Sources list.

Here you can see your GData API files that you added to your target like GTLNetworking_Sources.m and any other files. You need to flag these files as ARC disabled, so that Xcode can compile them as ARC disabled even when the project is ARC enabled.

For this go to Compile Sources. Double click on the GData API file and a popup window will appear. Copy and paste this -fno-objc-arc in the popup window. Repeat this for every GData API file you added to the target. Build the project.

This will help you solve your problem.